Magento 2.4.4p4 Cannot instantiate interface Magento\JwtUserToken\Model\JwtSettingsProviderInterface After disabling Magento_JwtUserToken
I am trying to disable Magento_JwtUserToken in Magento 2.4.4p4 Enterprise Edition due to don't want to use this feature as it causing difficulties for me to create revoke logout token function
I have reinstall composer and run all ugrade,dicompile,clear cache, and also copied this di.xml from here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/etc/di.xml
but it didnt fix the issue
Here is the error I extract from the var/log/debug.log
[2024-08-08T02:50:52.054077+00:00] report.CRITICAL: Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\JwtUserToken\Model\JwtSettingsProviderInterface in /var/www/html/wowshop/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:

Appreciate help
P.S : I refer to video on the Magento 2.4.4p4 implementation of JWT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bh9iEuAWTDo unfortunately even though in the video it seems to have no problem after disable the Magento_JwtUserToken it does create an issue for me
reading source on Magento JWT on Magento 2.4.4 : https://medium.com/@torhoehn/json-web-tokens-in-magento-2-4-4-cb8f8b86b4d9
